# Java spring framework interceptor issues

Tags: java, spring, maven, configuration, interceptor

I have been struggling to get my logging interceptor to work for three days now.

I feel have been all trough Stackoverflow and other tutorials on the internet, but I still haven't found a solution that works.

I'm using **Java 8** and **Spring framework 4.3.25.RELEASE**.

Here is my code.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public LoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor () {
        return new LoggingInterceptor ();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor( loggingInterceptor() );
    }
}


@Component
public class LoggingInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

  @Override
  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("preHandle");
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("postHandle");
  }

  @Override
  public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o, Exception e) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("afterCompletion");
  }
}
```

Could it be that I am not using a `@SpringBootApplication` annotation?

Comment: Start with ordinary debugging: Insert a trace statement or breakpoint in `addInterceptors` and see if it's being called.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I appreciate the quick reply and suggestion, but I have done that and addInterceptors breakpoint is never triggered.

Comment: Are you even using Spring MVC or Spring Boot? If you are using Spring Boot remove the `EnableWebMvc` and make sure it is in a package that is covered by the component-scanning. Finally you are using an `@Bean` method for your `LoggingInterceptor` so you don't need the `@Component`.

Comment: @M.Deinum in my pom.xml, among other dependencies, I am using spring-boot version 2.1.8.RELEASE and spring-webmvc version 4.3.25.RELEASE

Comment: @Eldridge When using Spring Boot, you should _almost_ never specify versions; Spring Boot 2 should be using Spring 5. Figure out why your configuration class is not being included in the Spring context (e.g., package organization).

Comment: Don't mix jars of different versions (Spring Boot 2.1 uses Spring 5.1).

Answer (score -1):

you can extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter,and override the method you sepcify.I will post my code below.

```
@Component
public class MyIntercepter extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response, Object handler) throws Exception {
return true;
}



@Configuration
    public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    
        @Override
        public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
                registry.addInterceptor(myIntercepter);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think this solution would work with spring framework 5+

Comment: This isn't a solution to the problem, as the registration isn't happening, changing the implementation of the interceptor won't change the registration process.

Comment: Sorry. I did not see spring frameword version clearly.